# Python difference between 'import as' vs variable assignment

Tags: python, import, python-import

How do the following two statements differ and what are the consequences of each?

Import as:

```
from module.submodule import someclass as myclass
```

Assign to a variable:

```
from module.submodule import someclass
myclass = someclass
```

Comment: Effectively the same thing.

Comment: There *are* differences, check the bytecode.

Comment: Same thing, u are assigning it to a variable in global space of your current script

Comment: PyCharm for one cannot show me Quick definition or Go to source, when I use the second approach (Assignment to variable), but it works fine when I use the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytecode output given here is for Python 3.4, but the code to produce the bytecode should work on any version and the same general principles apply.

Harness:

```
from dis import dis

def compile_and_dis(src):
    dis(compile(src, '<string>', 'exec'))
```

Case 1:

```
>>> compile_and_dis('from module.submodule import someclass as myclass')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (('someclass',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module.submodule)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (someclass)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (myclass)
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is the only approach that only adds one name (`myclass`) into the current `locals()` (i.e. `__dict__`, which will become `globals()` for everything defined in the module). It is also the shortest bytecode.

This method will raise `ImportError` if `someclass` is not found in `module.submodule`. It will, however, attempt to load `module.submodule.someclass` as a module.

Case 2:

```
>>> compile_and_dis('from module.submodule import someclass; myclass = someclass')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (('someclass',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module.submodule)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (someclass)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (someclass)
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (someclass)
             19 STORE_NAME               2 (myclass)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is nearly identical to case 1, except that it leaks a second name (`someclass`) into the local namespace. If the import and assignment are not contiguous, you do run the theoretical risk of reusing the name for something else, but if you're shadowing names you have horrible design anyway.

Note the useless `STORE_NAME`/`LOAD_NAME` cycle in the bytecode (around an unrelated `POP_TOP`).

Case 3:

```
>>> compile_and_dis('from module import submodule; myclass = submodule.someclass')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (('submodule',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (submodule)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (submodule)
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (submodule)
             19 LOAD_ATTR                2 (someclass)
             22 STORE_NAME               3 (myclass)
             25 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

This approach leaks `submodule` into the local namespace. It does not raise `ImportError` if the class is not found, rather it raises `AttributeError` during the assignment. It does not attempt to load `module.submodule.someclass` as a module (and in fact doesn't even care whether or not `module.submodule` is a module).

Case 4:

```
>>> compile_and_dis('import module.submodule as submodule; myclass = submodule.someclass')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module.submodule)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (submodule)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (submodule)
             15 LOAD_NAME                1 (submodule)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                2 (someclass)
             21 STORE_NAME               3 (myclass)
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is similar to case 3 but requires that `module.submodule` be a module.

Case 5:

```
>>> compile_and_dis('import module.submodule; myclass = module.submodule.someclass')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module.submodule)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (module)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (module)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                2 (submodule)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                3 (someclass)
             21 STORE_NAME               4 (myclass)
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

This approach is similar to case 4, although the 2 attribute loads are at different places so a different variable leaks into the local namespace.

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that in your variable assignment example, `someclass` is still available as a name. That'll lead to issues when importing types with the same name.

```
from datetime import datetime
from arrow import datetime  # problem!
```

To fix this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from arrow import datetime as arrow_datetime
```

Comment: Any ideas why PyCharm cannot show Quick definition or Go to source on `someclass.some_attribute_or_method`, when I use the second approach (Assignment to variable), but it works fine when I use the first one?